# Cheap places for MSDN Licenses

Tags: msdn

A similar question has been asked: [MSDN subscriptions on the cheap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466/msdn-subscriptions-on-the-cheap), but I am not interested in the solutions provided:

- I am not developing a product for sale, I am starting up a consulting company, so Empower is not an option.
- I have visited the links to MS regarding MSDN subscriptions and they *do not* point to a way to get an inexpensive copy.
- I am not interested in suggestions that I become a MVP.  Frankly, I'm desiring to focus on developing my company, not jumping through MS's hoops.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing not programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the Action Pack: https://partner.microsoft.com/US/40016455.

(Note, as an employee of Microsoft, I apologize that you have to LOG OUT of your LiveID to see this page if that LiveID is not already attached to a Registered Partner.)

You don't have to be certified to get access to this, just registered (there are three levels of partnership: 1. Registered, 2. Certified, 3. Gold Certified). You do have to pass a fairly simple assessment test, though.

See the pdf referenced at https://partner.microsoft.com/US/40082823 for an overview of the process.

One last thing - if you are a student (I suspect the OP is not), you can get many Microsoft tools free from http://www.dreamspark.com.

Comment: Last link is broken. I think this is developer relevant - can I ask if the action pack is still available or what the latest news is?

Answer (score 5):

There are really only a few options available

1. Buy it at standard price
2. Become a Microsoft Certified Partner, and get a good discount (Actually much simpler than you would think, I did it in under 2 weeks for my business)
3. Find a MVP buddy that is willing to share a free giveaway

But in all reality, these are the ONLY legal options.  You might also try calling Microsoft, you never know what might happen, they have many special programs that are not necessarily publicly advertised.

Comment: What are the hoops you needed to do for being a MS CP?

Comment: I'm a one man shop, 1 phonecall to MS got me a voucher for free application testing, the app was tested, I associated my MCP id to my account, then got 3 client testimonials and Bingo!  Microsoft Certified Partner.

Comment: There is a simple 4th option, at least in the UK - buy it from a distributor.  They're always cheaper than MS directly.

Answer (score 2):

Surely your consultancy will need a website in ASP.NET and perhaps your clients would like a widget that talks directly to a web service on your site? There's your product.

Also, look into "Value added Services" amongst the Empower documentation.

I'm on the Empower program - there really aren't any barriers to entry, as such.

Answer (score 1):

I used to go directly through MS, but nowadays, I always order mine through [Xtras.net](http://www.xtras.net/) - they have good multi-year discounts and you manage the subscription online through Microsoft's site as normal.

Comment: The best I see is averaging $1200  / yr, but the money is all due up front.  Does that sound right?  Anyone take payments later on, once I've made money on it?

Answer (score 1):

Does Empower require that the 'main' use is developing a product?
You can always develop a product as well - doesn't have to be very sucessfull, perhaps something to display the time in a window?

Comment: You can call the Empower people, but in all reality from my understanding no it doesn't have to be very big, BUT it has to be functional at some point as really the end result is to get the organization to become a certified partner

Comment: The crazy thing is - I may _someday_ do a product, but not in the foreseeable/immediate future.  I would like to honor another company's terms, just as I hope others will honor mine.