# TechNet or MSDN Subscription?

Tags: msdn, subscriptions, technet

I'm just a one-man software shop, and I currently have an MSDN subscription. It is coming up for renewal soon, and it looks like it's going to cost a small fortune. I see that TechNet subscriptions cost significantly less money, and seem to include all of the same software. Am I missing something here? What is the difference between these 2 packages?

Update: The price of Visual Studio and a TechNet subscription is still less than the cost of an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If memory serves the TECHNET subscription is licenses for EVALUATION purposes, while the MSDN subscription is licenses for use as a Developer.

Answer (score 2):

Does TechNet include Visual Studio?

I thought that was one of the big differences.

Comment: I added an update to the question to address this, even buying VS separately it's still cheaper.

Comment: Then I think Stephen Wrighton hit on the other big difference that may be more important.

Answer (score 2):

TechNet includes a very different set of products, and is used for eval. Here's details on the different TN subscriptions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb892756.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check this question for [finding MSDN subscriptions on the cheap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466/msdn-subscriptions-on-the-cheap), though it sounds like you don't qualify for Empower.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a software shop, get MSDN. TechNet does not cover you for any dev/test scenarios!

Answer (score -3):

WTF do you people keep typing "Evaluation" for? On Microsoft's page listing the differences between a Technet and MSDN subscription they do not use the words Evaluate or Evaluation even once.. They say "use" a lot.. Then they specify what you can use it for. Technically, BOTH subscriptions are for the dictionary definition of evaluation of their software.

Examples::

MSDN: Become familiar and keep up to date with the latest Microsoft software to support your application development process.

So, you're allowed to evaluate their latest software in order tosupport your application development process.

TechNet: Become familiar and keep up to date with the latest Microsoft software to support internal or external clients using or deploying the software.

So, you're allowed to evaluate their latest software in order to support internal/external clients using or deploying the software.

See, they are different ways of evaluating their software, so it doesn't make sense for you to say TechNet is evaluation and MSDN isn't. If you want to get TECHNICAL, both of them are evaluation. They are not full licenses that never expire. However, in terms of what you're physically able to do with the subscriptions, with the exception of the free developer tools from MSDN, they aren't that differnet... (If you don't count price) -- Get a TechNet subscription and purchase Visual Studio. You'll be able to do the same things you were able to do w/MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for joining SO! I hope you enjoy your time here. I don't think we need to resort to swearing. If you have a comment on someone's answer, please enter it as a comment on their answer—otherwise, the answerer won't be notified of what you've said! (only the original asker of the question will)

Comment: The technet license specifically mentions that you can't use it for the development of commercial software.

Answer (score -4):

Evaluation purposes? Are they going to show up at your door to check to make sure you're using the software they gave you full license keys the way they want you to?

When you say evaluation people might infer that you are saying that the software expires or something. Sort of like the term. "Evaluation Period"

They give you product keys for the software included in each library that keep working even after your subscription expires.. If Technet is cheaper than MSDN, even when you purchase Visual Studio seperately, go with Technet. I have both, because I'm rich. There's not really a point to buy both, but whatever.. Save your damn money and get a Technet subscription.

Comment: You may not be aware that Microsoft has contracts with accounting firms to do pretty much exactly what you suggest in your first paragraph, and that the agreement you confirm when purchasing the subscription specifically mentions it.